# Sec/subsec in the margins

Tags: sectioning, margins

It is possible to put sec/subsec numbers in the margins (enlarged), on the left for even pages and on the rigth for odd pages? The corresponding titles must be left aligned on even page and rigth aligned in the odd pages.

Comment: Right now this isn't a question. Did you mix up the first two words and forget to put a question mark?

Comment: Are you constrained in terms of packages that you're currently using to create sectional units?

Comment: Yes, the titlesec package...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code should do about what you want, if I've well understood:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsproc

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec, xcolor}
\titleformat{name=\section,page=odd}{\color{red}\bfseries\itshape\Large\boldmath}  {\upshape\LARGE\llap{\thesection\hspace*{0.5em}}}{0ex}{}%%
\titleformat{name=\section,page=even}{\filleft\color{blue}\bfseries\itshape\Large\boldmath}{\upshape\LARGE\rlap{\hspace*{0.5em}\thesection}}{0ex}{\llap}%  
\titlespacing*{\section}{0ex}{1.8\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}%

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
Section title on an oddpage. Section title on an oddpage.Section title on an oddpage. Section title on an oddpage.  
\clearpage
Fiddle dee dee

\section{Another section}

 Section title on an even page. Section title on an even page. Section title on an even page. Section title on an even page. 
\end{document}
```

Results in 
[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

Comment: It's what I asked for. I think it is possible to extend the methods to chapers and to subsections. Thanks